# Enable Babel plugins in ember-auto-import for transpilation of imported library

Tags: ember.js, babeljs

I want to move some of utility functions and classes from my Ember app into a separate NPM library and import it with [`ember-auto-import`](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import). I don't want to transpile the library code before publication but publish in authoring format. This shouldn't be an issue as `ember-auto-import` transpiles the code automatically at build time depending on app's configuration.

But this code is experimental decorators feature as many Ember code these days does. Babel used by `ember-auto-import` throws an error that the `decorators-legacy` feature is not enabled:

> Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't
>   currently enabled

How can I enable it in the configuration of `ember-auto-import`? I only see an option to disable transpilation per dependency and custom webpack configuration in [`ember-auto-import`'s documentation](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import#customizing-build-behavior). I don't have much experience with Webpack. Is babel controlled through Webpack configuration?

---

<strike>I just noticed that I get the same error if I reference a dependency on local file system using `link` protocol. I don't see the error if I use `file` protocol. I'm using yarn.</strike> This issue was solved by deleting `node_modules` and installing dependencies in referenced addon.